# Can I make API calls to my Node server that is connected through Web Socket with my ReactJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket

I have front-end in ReactJS where I am integrating my backend in NodeJS through websocket(also using sharedb). 
https://github.com/share/sharedb

My setup for this is below:

```
import sharedb from 'sharedb/lib/client';
// Using a Reconnecting Web Socket https://github.com/share/sharedb/pull/138/files
import { default as WebSocket } from 'reconnecting-websocket';

export default class ShareService {
  constructor(location) {
    this.socket = new WebSocket(location);
    // Open WebSocket connection to ShareDB server
    const connection = new sharedb.Connection(this.socket);
    this.connection = connection;
    this.location = location;
  }

  close() {
    this.connection.close();
  }

  reconnect() {
    this.socket = new WebSocket(this.location);
    this.connection.bindToSocket(this.socket);
  }

  doc(collection, id) {
    const doc = this.connection.get(collection, id);
    return doc;
  }

  sendCommand(data) {
    this.socket.send(JSON.stringify({
      'a': 'command',
      'deviceType': 'web',
      ...data
    }));
  }
}
```

And when I need to call from React I do:

```
this.shareService.sendCommand({
        command: 'I_AM_COMMAND',
        payload: {
          activeAgendaId: 123,
        }
      });
```

I want to know if I can also make normal API calls to my Node from React even after `WebSocket connection` is there?

Comment: Yes.. websocket and http requests don't interfere. As long as your server is up and listening for your http request, it will be able to answer

Comment: I need a suggestion. I am performing an intensive task in NodeJS of concatenating audios which are stored in S3 bucket. So it needs quite bit a time to first download and then process using FFMPEG and SOX. I am sending a command from React to this task but when the user sends a new command then the previous one does not completes fully and terminated. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It depends on how you are invoking the task. May be your task gets auto cancelled when the next command comes in. If you expect a lot of tasks would be arriving and may be running in parallel, then try to use some job queue like https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull so you don't run many jobs at once and overload the  server.

Comment: SInce I have only this task which is time consuming so creating an API and just calling it from React would be ok, right?

Comment: It should be fine if the number of users are less. Assume your UI is being used by 100 people simultaneously and each one invoking a task, it would be 100 tasks running. Which is why i suggested the queue system. if you expect less users or less tasks then a simple call as u mentioned would be fine.

Comment: Just call the API through HTTP as you do normally. As @Panther said, the two protocols don't interfere with one another.

Comment: Thank you so much, for my usecase I guess API call would be fine.